# 3D scanner needs PC with static IP?

Tags: windows, networking

A 3D scanner here needs to be connected to a PC with a static IP address.

The PC is connected to small Windows workgroup.

Would you:

a) Give the PC a static IP address from within Windows 10

OR

b) Give the PC a static IP using by reserving its IP in the router

Comment: This reads like a homework question.

Answer (score 7):

In a home environment, I prefer to assign a static IP. It's quick and easy.

In a business environment, I prefer to use a reserved address via DHCP. If and when other components of the network infrastructure change, like the DNS servers or the gateway, it is easier to deploy the new values to multiple clients if the clients themselves are already configured to use DHCP for their configuration needs.

Comment: Amen to that. Even for a home-setup I would go the DHCP route. Just so the DHCP server (in the router) knows which ip-adddress are reserved for those "special" devices. In most home-routers this will also automatically create a DNS entry for the device with the reserved address in its local DNS database. This may greatly improve name-based lookups in the local LAN, so you don't need to rely solely on the (often flaky) broadcast or WINS mechanisms of Windows.

Comment: Agree on that with @Tonny. Using a static IP can cause problems on the long term if the component is disconnected enough time to get its IP lease time expired and other device coincidentally gets the same IP. You can assign an IP outside the DHCP range, but in my opinion is unconvenient to remember that for the next network changes, and if you are already connecting to the router, why not use DHCP reservations and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to set up Ip's in the router. I have had problems when Windows just reset some settings after one of it's "upates"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be to setup an individual network between your PC and printer. This is useful when:

1. You do not wish to alter, or have control over configurations of your existing network.
2. The printer, or whatever the device is, always communicate with one specific PC

Buy a new network card (USB-LAN adapter would suffice), install it on your PC, configure it to have a static IP. The configuration of other card(currently in use) and rest of network should remain as-is.